# ? Incorrect regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I’ve been trying to do find if a variable contains a digit inside of it. And for some reason, I put (exp.) ‘Majorpassword09’ and it just prints a false?

```js
// vars

var regex = new RegExp(‘.*\d.*’)
var str = ‘Scorpio08’

// main
function reg1() { 
    if (regex.test(str)){
        console.log(‘true’);
    }else{
        console.log(‘false’);
    }
}
reg1();
```

EDIT: I’ve put the title as Incorrect regex expression because that's the only thing that I think is wrong.

Comment: Your code currently throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token @ JS line 3`. Consider correcting your syntax first.

Comment: Are the single single quotes the same as in your code? If so those are incorrect and should be replaced with `'`.

Comment: Why not use the tried and tested `/^\d+$/.test(str)`

Comment: you have to escape the backslash when using the quoted form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're most likely on a mac.
Your code shows that you're using *fancy* quotes. Like these ones: `‘’`. You need to use *normal* quotes, like `'`, and `"`.

Here's a solution to your problem.

```js
// vars

var regex = new RegExp(".*\\d.*")

var str = "Scorpio08"

// main

function reg1() { 
if (regex.test(str))
{
console.log("true");
}else{
console.log("false");
}
}

reg1();
```

Whatever text editor you're using, it has fancy quotes on. Consider looking in the settings, or on Google, to find out how to disable them.

Comment: The RegExp constructor normally expects a pattern string. It only accepts another regex since ES5. So this should be either `new RegExp(".*\\d.*")` or `/.*\d.*/`, because `new RegExp(/.*\d.*/)` is quite an unlogical thing to do.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Alright, then. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Since ``\`` is a special character within string context you'll have to escape it with another ``\``. `".*\d.*"` is the literal `.*d.*` whereas `".*\\d.*"` is the literal `.*\d.*`

Comment: I’ve tried putting this into jsitor and I’ve done everything you’ve described here but I still just get script error and thats it

Comment: @3limin4t0r Whoops! Sorry about all that!

Comment: @StarterScripter Unfortunately, I can't tell why. It works fine on JSitor for me. Maybe you're still using fancy quotes?

Comment: @SuperJumpBros Yeah, I think this is something with my device. It keeps just giving me 2 diffrent script errors with have no data and nothing is printed. I’ll try restarting.

Answer (score -1):

as you are using `string` to create a RegExp Object thus have to use two backslashes to properly escape

```
var regex = new RegExp(‘.*\\d.*’)
```

or

```
var regex = /.*\d.*/
```